# QA Requirements for KIK Integration

Tags: kik

1. Blacklist: We are using KIK's blacklist. We screen for words that match that blacklist exactly/completely. That means, if a player were to nest a blacklisted word in more characters before and/or after that word, we would not reject that entry. For instance, "ahole" would be rejected, but "uraholedood" would be accepted. 
   Q: How restrictively does KIK's QA need us to apply its blacklist? We're currently screening for exact matches within KIK's blacklist.
2. Load Time / Stopwatch Timings: Does this apply just to the load of the launch screen? or does this apply to the load time of every screen transition?
   And which connection should we be testing over (eg 3G, WiFi)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Kik is a mobile web browser so there are no QA requirements for having your website show up in the browser. So I'm going to assume that you are referring to some form of promotion for Kik (ads, featuring, etc)

1. Kik doesn't have an officially documentated blacklist of words. The documentation says websites must be PG13 to show up in search or Top Sites (http://dev.kik.com/build/#search). So basically use your judgement in terms of deciding what should/shouldn't be shown
2. Kik overlays a white loading screen on top of websites until the JavaScript `window.onload` event fires. Websites should make as much of an effort to have users not see that screen. The stopwatch timings refer to that screen specifically. This is again more of a general metric as it is very difficult to estimate what the average user will experience without actual data